# An unknown error occurred. could not find repository from <a valid local path> (-1)

Tags: swift, package, package-managers

Xcode isn't totally happy with my Package.swift file.
This is the line with an issue;

```
.package(name: "Utilities", url: "file:///Users/Alexander/Development/MMXX/Repositories/Utilities", from: Version("1.0.0"))
```

The package is a local package I have created, and is in use for a few other apps, so I know it is a valid package and its location is correct.

The Version 1.0.0 is "made up" in the sense that I haven't declared a version anywhere and didn't know what else to put there. It was the only thing I tried that Xcode was able to parse successfully -- it parsed the information, it just can't match it to my local repository.

The package was created using Xcode, and I didn't issue any commands to make it a git repository. Do I need to update my app's plist to allow disk access to a folder outside the app's sandbox?

Any pointers what else I can try would be most appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what finally worked:

in the `dependencies:` section

```
 .package(path: "../Utilities")
```

in the `targets:` section

```
.product(name: "Utilities", package: "Utilities")
```

Edit:

I ran into this problem again.  I dragged the package folder into the active project and it loaded the referenced libraries.  But it wouldn't compile (couldn't find the new package).

Make sure you select the target and navigate to "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content", click on the "+" and add the package:

[image: Xcode View]

Comment: Did not work for me: `Package.swift:36:10: Type 'Array<Target>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Target') has no member 'product'`

Comment: Did you define your product name at the beginning of your product declaration? "let package = Package( name: "Utilities","

Comment: Yes, but anyway I'm trying another approach. Thanks

Comment: OK. I know how frustrating it is that sometimes things work and sometimes they don't. 